# Does anyone know how to get rid of flickering particles in THREE.js

Tags: three.js, flicker, particles

i have tried the following materials settings:
alphaTest: 0.5
transparent: true,
Textures sizes only power of 2 (64 or 256)
assigning zero values to texture (prior to release 51 )
texture : { type: "t", value:0, texture: this._texture }, r50
using larger particles sizes

http://www.cimmerian-space.com/f3d/html/Particle_flicker.html

It seems to have something to do with Particle Sorting / Depth Buffering.
The funny thing is when you try to isolate the problem it goes away , its only the interaction of particles that causes this.

if you delete line 232 
Trade_fleet = initTradeFleet(10,100,pos03,THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("http://www.cimmerian-space.com/images/particles/Asteroid3_64.png"),100,75,100 );

the flickering stops completely. All that function does is declare a new sparks ... everything else is commented out.

All i can think of is that there is a floating point inaccuracy in particle sorting. it would be nice to have a 'SortingNeedsUpate' field on particle system, or that the sorting is only updated when the camera moves.

Seems to occur only in Chrome and not Mozilla